# Home server becomes unresponsive after indeterminate time

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, hardware-failure

I've been having an issue with a home server of mine (mostly used for plex) becoming unresponsive after steadily decreasing amounts of time.

I originally noticed the issue a few months ago but put off dealing with it as it was only occurring around once every two weeks. In the last week however the issue has increased in frequency to the point where it locks up every few hours.

I was originally running ubuntu 17.10, then upgraded to 18.04 with the issue occurring consistently for each operating system. After spending days poring over the logs and being unable to find anything of substance and at my wits end I decided to start from scratch with a minimal install of Centos 7. On this I just installed docker then ran plex as a containerised service, this seemed to be working fine during the install, yet, sure enough, come that evening the server had become unresponsive again.

I then suspected that maybe there was an issue with the memory so I ran a memory test which returned a clean bill of health and ran fsck's on all the devices disks which returned no issues

The nature of this 'unresponsiveness' is that there is no output to the connected monitor and no response from any keyboard or mouse input. Additionally any ssh sessions currently active on the machine will freeze and become unresponsive.

One odd thing is that the machine will, at least in the early stages of its 'unresponsiveness', respond to pings and any new ssh sessions I attempt to open will just hang as if waiting for a response. However, after some time this behaviour ceases and the device simply appears to not exist on the network.

The whole time this is happening the device appears to be operating fine with all fans, leds etc. operating apparently normally.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated as I am somewhat at a loss as to how to proceed.

The Components of my computer are as follows:

```
Motherboard: GIGABYTE GA-AB350M-Gaming 3
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 1600 Desktop CPU
GPU: MSI NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 GAMING X 6 GB GDDR5
RAM: Corsair CMK16GX4M2B3000C15 Vengeance LPX 16 GB (2 x 8 GB) DDR4 3000 MHz
SSD: Crucial CT512MX100SSD1 512GB MX100 SATA
PSU: EVGA 650 W G2 GOLD 80+ Modular PC Power Supply Unit
Additional Storage: 2 x Seagate 4 TB BarraCuda 3.5 Inch 5400 RPM Internal Hard Drive
```

Comment: So you have gaming rig just sitting there in the network as a media server? Something that a Raspberry Pi or similar or even an Android box could do perfectly?

Comment: It used to be my gaming rig but I just haven't been interested in gaming for a while. I use it for a few other things in addition to plex which require more large-scale processing power and I'll probably start gaming on it again at some point in the future, providing I can fix this issue of course.

Comment: Such issues are very hard to troubleshoot. Other than recommending the usual stuff - update BIOS/UEFI and drivers - I can't think of anything else. And knowing the same happens with a minimal Linux it could  be hardware problems very hard to pinpoint.

Comment: I haven't actually tried updating the bios so maybe I'll give that a shot, Then I guess I'll see how long I can keep a usb booted distro running for to rule out anything related to the hard drive. Not sure how I can diagnose an issue with the motherboard or psu short of buying another and swapping them out. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: The devices  I suggested for the purpose in the first comment also require 1/20 of the electricity power you're using with this one. Something that  perhaps you should factor in.

Comment: Is the monitor in graphics mode or text mode? If the former, switch to the first virtual terminal (Ctrl-Alt-F1), possibly you'll see error messages. Did you look at the system logs for anything odd?

Comment: I flashed the BIOS with the most recent version and that seems to have resolved it! Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as per GabrielGarcia's suggestion I flashed the BIOS with the most recent version and that seems to have resolved the issue.